# Unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, xvfb

I am trying to run a mobile web test using appium on Centos 6 **headless linux** but I am keep getting this error:

```
"info: [CHROMEDRIVER STDERR] No protocol specified

info: Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.","origValue":"**unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb\n**  (Session info: chrome=webview)\n  (Driver info:chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux 2.6.32-042stab088.4x86_64)"},"sessionId":"8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22"}
POST /wd/hub/session/8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22/element/0.06753459526225924-1/value 500 1927ms - 395b

debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/8563fbe5972f3ba87673c7a082d49d22

debug: Request received with params: {}

info: Shutting down appium session..."
```

It opens up the chrome browser and navigates to the given url. After that it tries `sendKeys` to the username field and then it fails.

Comment: Have you fix that issue ? I am facing the same issue. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Please find a possible solution here:
http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

It works for me on Ubuntu, maybe similar solution works on CentOS.
For some reson I had to start Xvfb with bigger framebuffer

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 4000x2000x8
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `xvfb-run` to wrap the Appium server call, otherwise Appium will not be able to use the Xvfb server:

```
xvfb-run appium <server switches>
```